# How do I alias a command line command? (Mac)

Tags: python, command-line, command, alias

I'm on a mac, and I write quite a bit of python scripts.

Every time I need to run them, I  have to type '`python script_name.py`'. Is there I way to make it so I only have to type like '`p script_name.py`'? It would save some time :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am assuming you are running your script from the command line right? If so, add the following line as the first line in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or alternatively

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

in case the python command is not located in `/usr/bin`, and then issue the following command once at the Unix/terminal prompt (it makes your script "executable"):

```
chmod +x script_name.py
```

from then on you only need to type the name of the script at the command prompt to run it. No `python` part of the command needed. I.e., simply

```
./script_name.py
```

will run the script.

You can also of course go with the `alias`, but the above is a cleaner solution in my opinion.

For the alias

```
alias p="python"
```

should go into your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: this is the best way, in my opinion. however, are you sure the precise path on a mac will be `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: The more portable approach is to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I was just typing that :-)

Comment: @SimeonVisser I've seen posts that have advised against it (though I use it myself) since it may pick up a different version of Python (if there are more than one installed)

Comment: Thank you! I never put the #!/usr/bin/python comment because I never knew what I did. Thanks! I assume if I have a shell script I can do something like #!/usr/bin/bash and achieve the same effect but with shell? Thanks!

Comment: @PlazmotechBinary That's *exactly* right, though of course it depends on where the command is located. For instance, my default shell is the `tcsh`, but my shell scripts are all `bash` scripts, so I have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the scripts. To locate a command (it'll give you a series of directories, you usually want the first) use the `whereis` command. E.g., `whereis bash` or `whereis python`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `alias` command:

```
alias p="python"
```

You'll probably want to add this to your ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an alias to your `~/.profile` file:

```
alias p="python"
```

Note that you can also make a Python script executable with `chmod +x script.py`. You can then execute it using:

```
./script.py
```

You will need to add the following line to the top of your Python code for this to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This is called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Note that the details of the `alias` command depend on whether you are using the `bash` shell or the `tcsh` shell (or another one).

Comment: I typically use `#!/usr/bin/env python` which typically finds python even if it's in a weird place.

Comment: @mgilson: I've just updated the post to include this more portable shebang, it's indeed better to use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add aliases in the `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
alias gs="git status"
alias gc="git commit -m"
alias ga="git add"

alias p="python"
```

Then close and reopen the terminal to apply the changes.