# I Am Getting An Error When I Update Pip. How Can I Update Pip Without An Error?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to upgrade python's pip from version 19.3.1 to 20.0.2.
Python is on version 3.8
When I enter `"python -m pip install --upgrade pip"` to update pip all I get is the error message:

```
"ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 446, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 858, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 487, in move_wheel_files
    wheel.move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 594, in move_wheel_files
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 402, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 330, in make
    return super(PipScriptMaker, self).make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 391, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 295, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 231, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\43898\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 370, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."
```

I've tried manually updating pip, reinstalling to the newest version of python 3.8.2, uninstalling python then installing again. With no success. Pip also isn't installing new packages either.
I hope I have included enough to solve my problem.

Comment: Try: `python -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: Python wasn't recognised as a command but when i changed i to py it came up with the same error @AlexSusanu

Comment: `python` not being recognised as a command suggests something wrong with your  `python` installation. Have you tried running a simple code or reinstalling `python`?

Comment: Can you do a `where python` and `where pip`

Comment: If i type "py" into cmd it runs python so its working somehow? @CibinJoseph

Comment: The `py` command is a wrapper to select any of the python versions. It is always better to explicitly specify which version you'd like to run the program with; by using `py -2` or `python3` or so on. Take a look at the documentation or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742093/how-to-access-python-from-command-line-using-py-instead-of-python to see how `py` works. And finally, ensure you have pip installed for that *same* python version.

Comment: @Prudhvi when i type the pip command straight into cmd it says that pip is not recognized and when i enter python from cmd then type the pip command it says that install which is in the pip command isn't recognized.

Comment: @AlexSusanu where python and where pip doesn't work

Comment: I think i have fixed it, I entered py -m pip install --user --force-reinstall -U pip into cmd and it says it has successfully updated

Comment: Thankyou for those who contributed