# On writing, > py --version result is "No installed python found!" But When I write >python --version then it would display the python version. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

On writing, `py --version` result is "No installed python found!" But when I write `python --version` then it would display the Python version. Why does the result differ AND WHY doesn't it display Python version with `py --version`?

Why doesn't it display Python version when I write `py --version` and
why does it say "No installed python found!"

It only displays Python version on writing `py --version`.

Comment: What happens if you run `which py` and `which python`?

Comment: @TheCodingPenguin The usage of `py` suggests the program is called `where`, not `which`.

Comment: Because having `py` suggests the OS is Windows? I hadn't seen it that way, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Because there is no binary program called `py` in your environment. But there is a `python`. You can on Unix/Linux use `which` to figure this out.

It sounds like you are on Windows; there you need to examine `%PATH%`. See this answer for more ideas: [CMD opens Windows Store when I type 'python'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58754860/7157204)

```
(py3.8.16) user$ which python
/Users/user/.virtualenvs/py3.8.16/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 3.8.16
(py3.8.16) user$ py --version
-bash: py: command not found
(py3.8.16) user$
```

Comment: `py` should be install with Python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32742619/146625