# How to use python2.7 with python command?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have to install little bit older Python 2.7 :

Now to use it every time I need to use python2.7. For example:

For Example to Check the latest python version; I need to use below command

```
python2.7 -V
```

and it is giving proper results back like below:
    Python 2.7.13

But I want to use that with **python command**. Something like python2.7.

**How can I do this? How can I do python -V and verify something like Python Python 2.7.13?**

Comment: `$ alias python=python2.7`?

Comment: @hoefling - yeah exactly I want to achieve that

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Which part of the question is unclear to you?

Comment: what's unclear is that there's all that text showing that you compiled python, then you ask for `alias`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I am new to python..  Yeah i am stuck with command alias

Comment: ok, this has nothing to do with python. It's a bash/shell question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - i described steps I taken

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I'll edit question accordingly.  if it is too descriptive

Comment: yeah. Sorry for being sarcastic, it's for the sake of the explanation: you didn't explain how you booted your pc or where you bought it. So no need to explain _all_ the things you did before. Also read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986155/how-do-i-alias-a-command-line-command-mac

Comment: maybe you don't want an alias but a symlink.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - ok :) I am going to rewrite it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -  Thanks I am going to try symlink

Comment: there's nothing wrong with renaming your executable or creating a symlink in the same dir so path works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it by using the command

```
python2.7 yourfile.py
```

to run your file. If you just use the command

```
python yourfile.py
```

then it will take the latest python version installed or the default version of python to compile and run your program. If you want to make python2.7 as the default python you want to use you can type this command

```
alias python=python2.7
```

:)